# MVVMCross: ClearBindings() - How to use in Touch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

How does the `ClearBindings()` work in MvvmCross?

As for testing purposes, I'm simply trying to clear my TableView's itemsSource in `ViewDidLoad()` for WeekSelectorView.  Here's what I've tried, but nothing seems to work.

("this" refers to my current instance of WeekSelectorView)

```
var source = new WeekSelectorTableSource(TableView, this);
TableView.Source = source;

var set = this.CreateBindingSet<WeekSelectorView, WeekSelectorViewModel>();
set.Bind(source).To(vm => vm.Options);
set.Apply();

//None of these work
this.ClearBindings (this);
this.ClearBindings (source);
this.ClearBindings (TableView.Source);
this.ClearBindings (source.ItemsSource);
this.ClearBindings ("ItemsSource");
this.ClearBindings ("source.ItemsSource");
this.ClearBindings ("TableView");
this.ClearBindings ("TableView.Source");
this.ClearBindings (TableView);
this.ClearBindings ("TableView.Source.ItemsSource");
this.ClearBindings (set);
this.ClearBindings ("set");
this.ClearBindings ("Options");

TableView.ReloadData();
```

Currently, when I load the app, my WeekSelectorView loads the table based off my ViewModel's data.  I want to clear the binding though, so there shouldn't be any table at all.

```
this.ClearAllBindings();
```

The above line works, but I don't want to clear ALL the bindings, I just want to clear my TableView's ItemsSource.

---

Edit:

I currently have a WeekSelectorView that has a .xib associated with it.  In the .xib is a TableView (among other user controls).

My WeekSelectorView sets the source to my own class "WeekSelectorTableSource".  This tablesource class determines the number of rows/sections based on the ItemsSource binding.  It then creates some custom .xib cells and within my GetOrCreateCellsFor

```
    protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
    {
        var weekSelectorCell = WeekSelectorCell.Create();

        var set = _WeekSelectorView.CreateBindingSet<WeekSelectorView, WeekSelectorViewModel>();

        //Using string bindings since bindings with an index doesn't work  
        //ex: vm => vm.Options[indexPath.Row].Title
        set.Bind(weekSelectorCell).For(wc => wc.Title).To(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Options, indexPath.Row, Title)).OneWay();
        set.Bind(weekSelectorCell).For(wc => wc.Date).To(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Options, indexPath.Row, DateString)).OneWay();
        set.Bind(weekSelectorCell).For(wc => wc.Hours).To(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Options, indexPath.Row, TotalHours)).WithConversion(new HoursDecimalToHoursMinutesConverter(), null).OneWay();
        set.Apply();

        return weekSelectorCell;
    }
```

Now the reason why I want to `ClearBindings()`......

Every time I reload the table, my previous bindings persist.  So, if I bind 4 cells with 3 bindings each, the first time my app will have 12 bindings associated with the cells.  Once I reload the table (still with 4 cells) there will be 24 bindings....then 36, 48, etc.

Here's part of the Diagnostics....

```
2013-07-16 16:26:03.950 FCXiOSv2[569:21e03] MvxBind: Warning: 1259.41 Weak Target is null in MvxWithEventPropertyInfoTargetBinding - skipping set
2013-07-16 16:26:03.951 FCXiOSv2[569:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 1259.41 Receiving setValue to Week
2013-07-16 16:26:03.952 FCXiOSv2[569:21e03] MvxBind: Warning: 1259.42 Weak Target is null in MvxWithEventPropertyInfoTargetBinding - skipping set
2013-07-16 16:26:03.953 FCXiOSv2[569:21e03] MvxBind: Diagnostic: 1259.42 Receiving setValue to 7/8/13 - 7/14/13
2013-07-16 16:26:03.954 FCXiOSv2[569:21e03] MvxBind: Warning: 1259.42 Weak Target is null in MvxWithEventPropertyInfoTargetBinding - skipping set
```

I'm just getting FLOODED with this message after I reload my table, so I wanted to clear my bindings each time before I `TableView.ReloadData()`.

---

Edit:

After thinking it over and talking with a coworker who works with Windows native bindings, I found out there was a LOT of things I was doing wrong, long story short, I don't need to use `ClearBindings(view)`.

I had my out-most view handling all the binding, so as a view was reloaded (aka cells in a table), the bindings still persisted because the out-most view hadn't been deallocated.  So, all my subviews never handled their own bindings, which was a major mistake.

To fix change this (to the 'proper' way I'd imagine) I had my custom cell inherit from MvxTableViewCell and added a delay binding.

```
public WeekSelectorCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
{
    this.DelayBind (() => 
    {
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<WeekSelectorCell, WeekViewModel>();
        set.Bind(DateLabel).For(lbl => lbl.Text).To(vm => vm.DateString);
        set.Bind(HoursLabel).For (lbl => lbl.Text).To(vm => vm.TotalHours).WithConversion(new HoursDecimalToHoursMinutesConverter(), null);
        set.Bind(TitleLabel).For(lbl => lbl.Text).To(vm => vm.Title);
        set.Apply();
    });
}
```

I tried this before but tried to create a set between `<WeekSelectorCell, WeekSelectorViewModel>`  and tried to access (vm => vm.Options[ROW].Date), but this always failed.  I finally learned I needed to create a set between `<WeekSelectorCell, WeekViewModel>` because `Options[]` is an `ObservableCollection` of `WeekViewModel`

Like I said, long story short, I don't need to use `ClearBindings(view)`

Comment: Thanks for the long story - very helpful... I still think there might be other cases where removing bindings might be useful (that was the original intention of the droid `ClearBindings(view)` method - so this will probably appear in the iOS version soon! Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does the ClearBindings() work in MvvmCross?

`ClearBindings()` is `ClearBindings(view)`

Each `MvxBindingContext` maintains 3 separate lists of 'bindings':

1. a list of bindings created directly on the context
2. a view-based lookup table of bindings created within child views - these are currently only used in Android bindings when child views are inflated dynamically within the parent binding context.
3. a list of actions (which generally go on to create bindings) which are waiting for the first call to `DataContext=value`

The first of these is currently the main one used in iOS - and the only public clear API that `MvxBindingContext` exposes for that list is `ClearAll`.

The second one is used only in Android for some child view Xml inflations - and `ClearBindings(view)` allows these to be used for that.

The history behind all of these is especially tied to lots of issues with memory management within both Android and iOS - especially with trying to make sure we tracked and disposed of all bindings, including those created within subviews, within lists, etc.

---

If we can dig out a good use case here here - something a little expanded from "this is only for some testing purposes" - then a `ClearBindingsForObject` or `EnumerateBinding` API would be something that could be considered for an expanded binding context API - but it would definitely need a stronger requirement to make sure the project captured what the API is really useful for.

In the meantime, I guess you could create and register the binding using the tableView as a lookup if you wanted to - e.g. something like:

```
var bindings = MvxBindingSingletonCache.Instance.Binder.Bind(BindingContext.DataContext, tableView, "ItemsSource MySource");
this.RegisterBindingsFor(tableView, bindings);
```

That would then enable you to call `ClearBindings(tableView);`

---

Alternatively, if you wanted to stop an individual binding from working then you could `Dispose` it early - that would clear it's source binding - e.g. if you did:

```
    _myDisposableBindings = MvxBindingSingletonCache.Instance.Binder.Bind(BindingContext.DataContext, tableView, "ItemsSource MySource");
    this.AddBindings(_myDisposableBindings);
```

then you could at some point later do something like:

```
    foreach (var binding in _myDisposableBindings)
    {
        binding.Dispose();
    }
    _myDisposableBindings = null;
```

---

Alternatively - and perhaps this is the way I'd go (although it depends on exactly what your use case is) - then it might be easier to just place your table in its own `MvxView` control - that can have it's own `BindingContext` which you can call `ClearAllBindings()` on.

For more on `MvxView` see http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/n32-truth-about-viewmodels-starring.html

---

Finally, I might also consider working out whether or not you could just keep the binding in place, but could instead clear the `ItemsSource` in your ViewModel.

Comment: truely fascinated by this topic - have created followup issue - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/358 - I'm mainly thinking about dynamic UIs, but also interested in this area of clearing bindings on static controls too (just not quite understanding the use case)