# MVVMCross Resource Loader

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

as I understand IMvxResourceLoader can load resources from platform-specific project's "Assets" or "Resources" folders. If that is true, is there a way/plugin that would load embedded resources from shared Core project? It would be convenient to maintain business logic  (or localisation) related resources in one place instead of copying them to ios/win/android projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it can be done. I have managed to put some assets (audio files) in core and used in main. Finally I returned it as Byte array; I am sure it can be played around to bind more.

Here is my code which I used

```
    public byte[] GetApplicationResource(ApplicationResourceName resourceName)
    {
        string resourcePath;
        switch (resourceName)
        {
            case ApplicationResourceName.AudioChord:
                resourcePath = AppConstants.ResourceNameAudioChord;
                break;

            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("resourceName");
        }

        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourcePath))
        {
            // sanity check
            if (stream != null)
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    return memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: actually I found the best answer in the examples of mvvmcross: I shoould store files in Core prj, add them as resources to other projects, but instead 'Add' I must do ‘Add as Link’. Build Action must be AndroidAsset (droid), Content (winphone, touch). And then use ResourceLoader plugin, GetResourceStream().
See http://slodge.blogspot.ca/2013/05/n21-internationalisation-i18n-n1-days.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get all references from the core project ( unfortunatelly =/ ).
There was another post similar to this one that you might find usefull:
[How to bind imageSource to ImageView in MvvmCross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142198/how-to-bind-imagesource-to-imageview-in-mvvmcross)

Hope it helps =)