# mvvmcross image resource loading extension requirements

Tags: android, ios, mvvmcross

I'm using an MvxImage widget (Android in axml) & UIImage + MvxImageLoader (iOS) to load UI images dynamically from the local resource using the resourceLoader Plugin. These are bound to strings in the viewmodel indicating which image to load. Binding works fine. Viewmodel image name strings use the res: prefix to make it work .

This works fine on Android when omitting the file extension (.png) in the bound string but doesn't find the resource when adding .png or .jpg.

example axml:

```
<Mvx.MvxImageView
local:MvxBind="ImageUrl ImgWifiStatus"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:scaleType="fitEnd"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
```

On iOS it's exactly the other way around. Images are not found in the resources without the .png extension in the bound string.

```
_wifiImgViewLoader = new MvxImageViewLoader(() => this.wifiImg);
set.Bind(_wifiImgViewLoader).To(vm => vm.ImgWifiStatus);
```

Is there a way to make this work in a similar way across the 2 platforms or do I have to use a valueconvertor on iOS to add the extension to a bound filename string without extension.

Thanks

**EDIT**

This is the valueconverter that did the trick. Pretty straithforward. I'm using it at the same time to make all lowercase filenames and to allow for some flexibility on how to specify the desired extension.

```
public class AddFileExtensionValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<string, string>
{
    protected override string Convert(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        value = value ??  "";
        parameter = parameter ?? "";
        switch ((string) parameter)
        {
            case "PNG":
            case "png":
            case ".PNG":
            case ".png":
                return value.ToLower()  + ".png";
                break;
            case "JPG":
            case "jpg":
            case ".jpg":
            case ".JPG":
                return value.ToLower()  + ".jpg";
                break;
            case "GIF":
            case "gif":
            case ".gig":
            case ".GIF":
                return value.ToLower()  + ".gif";
                break;
        }
        return value.ToLower();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no way around this problem =/ . The current solution is using ValueConverters. 
There is a similar post with a converter here: [How to bind imageSource to ImageView in MvvmCross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142198/how-to-bind-imagesource-to-imageview-in-mvvmcross)

Hope it helps =)

Comment: Thx. I indeed used a valueconverter to do this. Works perfectly fine. I'll add it as an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the file extension in your source value, then you could register a custom `IMvxLocalFileImageLoader<Bitmap>` implementation to load your Android resources.

You could base your implementation - `MyAndroidLocalFileImageLoader` - on: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Plugins/Cirrious/DownloadCache/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.Droid/MvxAndroidLocalFileImageLoader.cs

You could change:

```
            var resourcePath = localPath.Substring(ResourcePrefix.Length);
            bitmap = LoadResourceBitmap(resourcePath);
```

to:

```
            var resourcePath = localPath
                                  .Substring(ResourcePrefix.Length)
                                  .ToLower()
                                  .Replace(".jpg", "")
                                  .Replace(".png", "");
            bitmap = LoadResourceBitmap(resourcePath);
```

You could then register your custom `MyAndroidLocalFileImageLoader` in your Setup in `InitializeLastChance`